# Is it possible to create a list of fibonacci numbers using [edit: a very limited set of knowledge]?

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

For instance, in the form of something like this:

```
let f = [ a | a <- [1..], a == a - 1]
```

I'm just curious. It seems like it'd be possible, but I can't quite wrap my head around how it would work. This question is meant more for understanding how Haskell works, not so much because I'm looking for a practical application.

Also, I know that similar questions have been asked, but none of the posts I looked at offered any help in doing it they way I'm curious about.

Edit: sorry for the vagueness. Let me clarify a new rule, then. The challenge is to find a way to represent an infinite list of fibonacci numbers using as little extra from the first chapter of Learn You A Haskell For Great Good! as possible. How's that? In other words, what's the most creative way you can think of to produce those numbers with as little 'knowledge' as possible. Sorry for making anyones answer invalid, now.

Comment: 1) `a == a-1` is always `False`. 2) you have `-`, that's not "only comprehensions". what exactly is the class of expressions that you want to allow? 3) can you give an example (for another arithmetic sequence) where this works they way you think it should?

Comment: That was just an example. I didn't think that would actually produce anything. It was listed under List Comprehensions in Learn You A Haskell, so that's what I thought it was called. But, like, in the way that you have 'such that' bar right there. That's what I meant. Is there a better term for that?

Comment: *" In other words, what's the most creative way you can think of to produce those numbers with as little 'knowledge' as possible"* makes this question a toy question or a programming puzzle, which would belong to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Data.List (tails)

fib :: [Integer]
fib = 0 : 1 : [ a + b | (a:b:_) <- tails fib ]
```

Yes it makes use of the cons operator `(:)` for the seed values. However I believe that can be pardoned.

Comment: it also uses self-referential data, a fixpoint in disguise (you can not change the name on the LHS without changing the RHS). And it uses the function `tails`, a stand-in for `zipWith ... tail` here. And list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible with a nasty trick: there's [a closed form of the Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Closed-form_expression)

> *f*<sub>*n*</sub> = (*φ*<sup>*n*</sup> - *ψ*<sup>*n*</sup>) / √5

so

```
Prelude> let (φ, ψ) = (1/2+s, 1/2-s) where s = sqrt(5/4)
Prelude> let fibs = [ round $ (φ^n - ψ^n) / sqrt 5 | n <- [0..] ]
Prelude> take 20 fibs
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181]
```

This works in floating point, so it's extremely fast but fails to work exactly at high values:

```
Prelude> take 3 $ drop 80 fibs
[23416728348467676,37889062373143896,61305790721611584]
Prelude> 23416728348467676 + 37889062373143896 - 61305790721611584
-12
```

I think it can not work without exploiting irrational numbers or putting some recursion in the comprehension, because list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for monadic binds and those by themselves aren't Turing-complete, so they can't generate an infinite sequence constructively.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but that is still very cool. Nasty tricks are great.

Comment: Argh. And here I was, looking for a proof that you need fixed-point iteration to implement `fib`, and that you need more than list comprehensions and the `Integer` instances of `Enum` and `Num` to achieve that...

Comment: @Rhymoid: I think such a proof does exist, if you prohibit irrational numbers or in some other way require constructibility.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: there is a proof that Fibonacci numbers are not context-free (Moll & Venkatesan, 1989), so it would suffice to prove that list comprehensions can only support context-free grammars. It might seem that way with just `concatMap`...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Irrational numbers are constructible! If you change `Double` to `CReal` everywhere in your implementation, you will suddenly find it works correctly even for large indices.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is of course:

```
fibs = f 0 1 where f a b = a : (f b (a+b))
```

We arrive at this solution from the definition.

Let `f a b` computes a stream of numbers starting with `a` and followed by `b`. Then we can use `f` to compute the substream of numbers following `b`, if we can compute the number following immediately after `b`. We know that immediately after `b` follows `a+b`, so we get that stream and append it to `a`.

Comment: this only uses `:`, `+`, and function call. The name `fibs` can be changed to anything, freely.

Comment: @WillNess yes, there probably is some sort of `scanl2 f a0 a1` :)

Comment: I meant that your solution is the most minimal, uses the least from the language. using `scanl` would mean using more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not involve any list library functions, using list comprehensions instead.

```
fib = [ x | (x,_) <- l ]
   where l = (0,1) : [ (b,a+b) | (a,b) <- l ]
```